# How can I get from Santa Susanna to BCN airport using public transit on a Saturday?

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, barcelona

I plan to travel from Santa Susanna (Torrentó De Can Gelat, S/N, 08398) to BCN airport (El Prat de Llobregat) on Saturday, the 27th of July.

For workdays, there's an option to use trains (R1, then R2) to get directly to the airport, but Google Maps does not show this option on Saturday.

For Saturday, it suggests buses 603 & 614, but I did not find the frequency of departures.

How can I get there by public transport? Would "Hola BCN!" ticket still apply?

Comment: this question has received some close votes, probably because it mentions "cheap way" - people start answering "you could walk", "try hitchhiking" etc. I've edited that out to focus on public transit which appears to be what you're looking for.

Comment: I don't see any service disruption to the Rodalies today. It looks like Google Maps is having an issue. Use the Citymapper app instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always have a second source of information that's not Google :-)

I like the Citymapper app, personally.

But the best in this case would be the official Rodalies site: http://rodalies.gencat.cat/en/alteracions_del_servei/index.html

Comment: Oh but i have no idea about the "Hola Bcn!" ticket I'm afraid. It'll probably be valid to get you back from Mataró to Barcelona, but they like to charge everyone extra to go to the airport these days and standard tickets are no longer valid. I get the Aerobus to the airport usually.

Answer (score 2):

You can go from Santa Susanna train station to BCN Airport train station on Saturday 27 july without any problem. As you have said, you have to take R1 line at Santa Susanna and then transfer to R2 at Barcelona Sants train station. The duration of the journey will be of approximately 1 hour and 45 minutes.

You can check schedules at [Rodalies de Catalunya website](http://rodalies.gencat.cat/en/horaris/): select From "Santa Susanna", Destination "Aeroport" and the date and time you want to start your journey.

As you can see [here](https://www.holabarcelona.com/tickets/hola-bcn-barcelona-travel-card), Hola Barcelona Travel Card is valid for "Rodalies de Catalunya" lines (that is, railway lines around Barcelona) and it's also valid to travel from Barcelona to Barcelona-El Prat airport using metro lines or R2 railway line. The problem is that it's only valid on what it's called "zone 1". I'm afraid [Santa Susanna is located at "zone 5"](https://www.atm.cat/web/en/zoning.php), so you cannot travel from Santa Susanna to the airport using Hola Barcelona Card. You may buy a ticket to travel from Santa Susanna to Barcelona Sants station and then use your Hola Barcelona card to go from Barcelona Sants to the airport, but that shouldn't be cheaper than buying a ticket from Santa Susanna to the airport as the [number of zones will be the same](http://rodalies.gencat.cat/en/tarifes/servei_rodalia_barcelona/nomes_rodalies/).